# Laravel optimize routes

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, routes, laravel-5

is there any chance to reduce the routes.php

i have for one Model methods for day, week, month and year operations. Here is the routes only for weekly operations, but i have the same for the other periods. Is there any chance to reduce them ?

```
Route::get('capacity/{capacity}/createweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.createweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@createweekly'
]);
Route::put('capacity/{capacity}/storeweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.storeweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@storeweekly'
]);
Route::get('capacity/{period}/activateweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.activateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@activateweekly'
]);
Route::get('capacity/{period}/deactivateweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.deactivateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@deactivateweekly'
]);
Route::get('capacity/{period}/deleteweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.deleteweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@deleteweekly'
]);
Route::get('capacity/{period}/editweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.editweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@editweekly'
]);
Route::post('capacity/{period}/updateweekly', [
    'as' => 'admin.capacity.updateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@updateweekly'
]);
```

Comment: Every route looks like doing something different. What do you mean by reducing them? Do you want to remove the functionality?

Comment: yeah they have different functionality, but i hope there is something like Route::get('url_like_the_method', ['as' => 'url_like_the_method'], 'uses' => 'Controller@method']); or to use the Route::resource() method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to group them:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.capacity.', 'prefix' => 'capacity'], function () {
        Route::get('{capacity}/createweekly', [
                'as' => 'createweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@createweekly'
            ]);
        Route::put('{capacity}/storeweekly', [
                'as' => 'storeweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@storeweekly'
            ]);
        Route::get('{period}/activateweekly', [
                'as' => 'activateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@activateweekly'
            ]);
        Route::get('{period}/deactivateweekly', [
                'as' => 'deactivateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@deactivateweekly'
            ]);
        Route::get('{period}/deleteweekly', [
                'as' => 'deleteweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@deleteweekly'
            ]);
        Route::get('{period}/editweekly', [
                'as' => 'editweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@editweekly'
            ]);
        Route::post('{period}/updateweekly', [
                'as' => 'updateweekly', 'uses' => 'CapacityController@updateweekly'
            ]);
    });
```

Comment: yeah, group is fine, but it does not reduce the lines of code :)

Comment: you can just write Route::controller('capacity', 'CapacityController');
but you will have to rewrite your controller and urls usage, also there will be no route names